# How to express this in regular expression?

Tags: regex

I need to capture all Upper and Lower case character strings other than `"FOO"` and `"BAR"`. How to do this?

I tried `[^(^FOO$)(^BAR$)]` but it doesn't work.

**Update**:

Actually I'm using this in a context, I am concatenating it with another regex

["(\w)+": _this_regex_ ]

For example ["abc":FOO] shouldn't be matched

All other types say ["abc":BAZ] should match

Comment: Does `["foo": abc]` must match or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a negative look ahead:

```
\["(\w+)"\s*:\s*(?!FOO\b|BAR\b)(\w+)]
```

- The `(\w+)` are capturing group, they store the key/value pairs inside variables (I guess that's what you want to do?)
- `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead: it will cause the regex to fail if what's inside matches.
- `\b` is a word-boundary: here it will make the loohahead match (and so fail the regex) only if `FOO` is followed by a non alphanum character (so `["foo": FOOLISH]` will be accepted by the regex)
- `\s` is a short for all type of whitespaces (spaces, tabs, newlines etc)

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/fM3uZ7

What you tried `[^...]` was a negative character range: it matches any character (and only one character) that's not inside the character range. And keep in mind that inside character ranges only `]`, `^` and `-` are special character (so `$` means `\$` and so on)

Comment: I think he wants to exclude only the uppercase versions of "FOO" and "BAR".

Comment: This matches `["abc":FOO]` but it shouldn't.

Comment: @JASON: Saw your update, edited my answer (on the basis you want to avoid only uppercase `FOO` or `BAR`, so I removed the `(?i)`)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
(?i)^(?!.*foo)(?!.*bar)
```

In action within perl script:

```
my $re = qr~(?i)^(?!.*foo)(?!.*bar)~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say (/$re/ ? "OK : $_" : "KO : $_");
}
__DATA__
["abc":FOO]
["abc":BAZ]
```

**output:**

```
KO : ["abc":FOO]
OK : ["abc":BAZ]
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?i)^(?!.*foo)(?!.*bar)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?i)                     set flags for this block (case-
                           insensitive) (with ^ and $ matching
                           normally) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    foo                      'foo'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    bar                      'bar'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This doesn't match `["foo": abc]`.

Comment: @Robin: AFAIK, it shouldn't because it contains `foo`.

Comment: Seemed to me the condition was on the value only, not the key... This is something the OP should probably clarify then.

Comment: @Robin: Yes, this needs clarification.